# Wrap a React hook and retain its types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

I want to wrap React query so I can present an error. How can I type the args, generic and return type to mirror `useQuery`?

```js
export function useRelocaterQuery<T>(...args: any): Foo {
                               // ^            ^     ^ type this to mirror useQuery()

  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const query = useQuery(...args);

  if (query.error) {
    enqueueSnackbar("some generic message");
  }

  return query;
}
```

I've seen you can do this with regular functions using an intermediary function (wrap) but I don't know how to extend this to a hook.

```js
const wrap = <T extends Array<any>, U>(fn: (...args: T) => U) => {
  return (...args: T): U => fn(...args)
}
```

Comment: *"...but I don't know how to extend this to a hook."* Hooks *are* regular functions. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since useQuery has 4 generics, every low level wrapper around useQuery also needs to have the same generics. useQuery itself also has 3 function overloads, so you'd have to pick one structure. The simplest solution is to use the object structure and basically copy whatever react-query is doing for the options. The return type can generally be inferred, or you need to use `UseQueryResult`:

```
export function useRelocaterQuery<
  TQueryFnData = unknown,
  TError = unknown,
  TData = TQueryFnData,
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey
>(
  options: UseQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>
): UseQueryResult<TData, TError> {

  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const query = useQuery(options);

  if (query.error) {
    enqueueSnackbar("some generic message");
  }

  return query;
}
```

---

As a side-note, I generally don't think that abstractions like this are preferred. First of all, calling `enqueueSnackbar` likely violates the rule that react render functions need to be pure, as it clearly produces a side-effect during render. So you'd have to put that in a `useEffect` at least to avoid problems with concurrent features in react 18 and onwards.

On top of that, there are better ways to do generic error handling. For example, to show error toasts, I can recommend [the global onError handlers](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-error-handling#the-global-callbacks) on the QueryCache:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: (error) =>
      toast.error(`Something went wrong: ${error.message}`),
  }),
})
```

If you need to closure over `enqueSnackbar` that comes from a hook, you need to create the QueryClient inside the render function of your App, so you need to make it stable by putting it into state

```
function App() {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => {
    return new QueryClient({
      queryCache: new QueryCache({
        onError: (error) =>
          enqueueSnackbar("some generic message");
      }),
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Oooh, yeah, I didn't really look at what the function was **doing**, just the types. Definitely impure.